# Pause a Groovy script during runtime

Tags: java, groovy

How would I pause a Groovy script **within the script** until a Java program tells the script to run again? The script will be embedded inside of a Java program.

Comment: how gets the groovy part called? ScripingEngine, Process, directly? Should the java program pause it or should it pause and wait until it receives a signal?

Comment: Pause until it receives a signal.

Comment: How do yo execute it? ScriptEngine, Process or directly through a call? In a separate thread or in line?

Comment: I use GroovyShell and bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities depending on how you actually call the script.

If you call it using a seperate process, you could wait for input from STDIN in your script and write to STDOUT in java.

If both just run in different threads of one JVM (this includes the execution via ScriptingManager), than you can use `obj.wait()` int the script and `obj.notify[All]()` in the java program.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could loop it so that it keeps waiting until the program ends? I have a function that fires when something occurs. What should I add in the function to make the thread wake up again?  

TL;DR
Is there a way to check if the object (Groovy script) hasn't finished yet?

Comment: What method do you use? STDIN or wiat/notify?

Comment: Where the groovy script should pause, add [obj].wait(), in the function that fires [obj].notify[All](). Then you could either wrap the script into an infinite loop or call it just after it finished. This can be archived by waiting in the java program for [anotherObj].wait() and getting notified at the end of the script by the script itself using notify.

Answer (score 0):

i never come across this need in usual process - since embedding a script usually you want it to call you back after it runs to completion

http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html

can run with binding work?
rem do not cross threads

Comment: I'm going to change the bindings while the script is running. Each script will represent an NPC, and I want to wait for player interaction.